# JavaScript iterating over object properties and the prototype chain

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, prototypal-inheritance, prototype-chain

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#Performance) states:

> Also, when iterating over the properties of an object, every enumerable property that is on the prototype chain will be enumerated.

So I tried this:

```
var x = {a: "I am a"};
var z = Object.create(x);

for( i in z )
{
    console.dir( i );

    if( i == "hasOwnProperty" ) {
        console.log( 'found hasOwnProperty' );
    }
}
```

Outputs only `a` but not `hasOwnProperty`. Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` is non-enumerable:

```js
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.prototype, 'hasOwnProperty')
  .enumerable // false
```

Therefore, it's not iterated by the `for...in` loop.

Comment: Thanks. What is meant by 'enumerable'? That might have been my misunderstanding.

Comment: @RobertRocha Properties have some internal flags: [[Writable]], [[Enumerable]] and [[Configurable]]. If a property has the [[Enumerable]] flag set to `true`, it will be enumerated by a for-in enumeration. See [§8.6.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.1)

Answer (score 1):

Because **hasOwnProperty** is not enumerable , you can test it using

```
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.prototype, "hasOwnProperty").enumerable)
```

Answer (score 0):

As answered above, each property of an object has an 'enumerable' flag. When the flag set to false the property will not be enumerated when iterating over object properties.

Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty is non-enumerable which mean is 'enumerable' flag set to false.

You can read an article I wrote on the topic [here](https://medium.com/@ron.yosef_42332/javascript-iterate-over-object-properties-b20fe67b5b9b) to deepen your knowledge.